# How to change the background radio button when selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like you to help me how to change the color of the button radio when I select. I will have various button radio by my Code, so when selecting another, what is already marked, has to continue, how to do this with jquery or JavaScript?

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="btn" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" id="motNovaFuncao" value=3 autocomplete=off> Nova Função
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" id="motRemanejamento" value=4 autocomplete=off> Remanejamento
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" id="motAumentoQuadro" value=5 autocomplete=off> Aumento de Quadro
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" id="motSubstituicao" value=6 autocomplete=off> Substituição de Colaborador
                        </label>                    
                    </div> 

                  </div>   
            </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('#identAbertura').change(function(){
                                    $('.btn').removeClass().addClass('btn').addClass('btn-default');
                                    $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
                                });
                                $('#identMov').change(function(){
                                    $('.btn').removeClass().addClass('btn').addClass('btn-default');
                                    $(this).parent().removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsuEa.png)

Comment: `so when selecting another, what is already marked, has to continue` this is not clear

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good, I'm from another country.
But my problem is as follows, when I select a radio button it changes color, when I select another, the first one that had selected also changes color, but could not do that.

Comment: then what will be he color of the first button selected?

Comment: When select another radio button, the previous radios which are marked shoud keep their state marked right ? If it is true, It sounds like you want to choose multiple radio buttons right ? If it is true why don't you use checkbox ?

Comment: For example, I have at the beginning of my form a radio button called sex, male or female, the person went there and selected male and the radio turned blue. In another part of the form I have another button called working hours, late or night, there when the person chooses an option, the sex radio button that he had already selected loses the color, that's the problem, do not know if it became clearer now.

Comment: i have added a answer. reply in comment if this help you out

Comment: I do not want to choose several, what is happening is that when I select another, the one that had already selected loses the color.

Answer (score 0):

Radio button color can't be changed.
But you can change it's background or text color.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked{ 
   background : red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery for that effect. Looks like you did not added jquery in your code

Here is the working fiddle

```js
$('.mot_solic').change(function(e){
 $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('selected')
 $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
 console.log($(this));
});
```

```css
.selected {
   background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="btn" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" class='mot_solic' id="motNovaFuncao" value=3 autocomplete=off> Nova Função
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" class='mot_solic' id="motRemanejamento" value=4 autocomplete=off> Remanejamento
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" class='mot_solic' id="motAumentoQuadro" value=5 autocomplete=off> Aumento de Quadro
                        </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-default">
                            <input type="radio" name="motSolic" class='mot_solic' id="motSubstituicao" value=6 autocomplete=off> Substituição de Colaborador
                        </label>                    
                    </div> 

                  </div>   
            </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```